# Discord Python Argument missing when it's defined

Tags: python, discord, arguments, embed

While coding my discord python bot, I was making 2 bot commands. One sends a webhook embed to a specified channel as a placeholder for the embed. The other command edits the embed that I just created as the embed placeholder. My code looks like this. When I run this, range2 is a required argument that is missing and get_embedID is defined as Price1.

```
@bot.command()
async def addEmbed(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(1234567890)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Placeholder')
    message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    get_embedID = message.id
    return get_embedID

@bot.command()
async def editEmbed(get_embedID, ctx, range1, range2):
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(get_embedID)
    embed = message.embeds[0]
    embed.title(title=f'Open for current prices:')
    embed.add_field(description=f'{range1} to {range2}')
    new_embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed.to_dict())
    await get_embedID.edit(embed=new_embed)`
```

When testing out my code in discord, I first run !addEmbed, and we have an embed placeholder successfully send, and my get_embedID variable has the message id for the embed I just sent.

Then, I run !editEmbed 123 456

I want the !editEmbed command to edit my embed I made in !addEmbed with the embed title and description I have in my editEmbed function with range1 being 123, and range2 being 456.

When I run this, range2 is a required argument that is missing and get_embedID is defined as range1.

I don't know how to make sure my get_embedID argument comes down to the editEmbed function in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The first reason you code didn't work is because `ctx` was after `get_embedID`. Since `ctx` is automatically passed in when the command's callback is called, it needs to be before the other parameters.

Also `embed.title` is an attribute (of type `str`) and cannot be called.
In the answer code bellow I changed to modifying the embed itself and fixed it to change the values of the attributes: `title` & `description`

Here I have also moved embed_id to a global variable and the `addEmbed` command then sets it.
Then when `editEmbed` is called it will use the embed_id set in `addEmbed`

```
embed_id = None

@bot.command()
async def addEmbed( ctx):
    global embed_id
    channel = bot.get_channel(1036408156923887746)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Placeholder")
    message = await channel.send(embed=embed)
    embed_id = message.id

@bot.command()
async def editEmbed(ctx, range1, range2):
    global embed_id
    message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(embed_id)  # get the me

    embeds = message.embeds # get embeds on message
    embed = embeds[0] # first embed
    embed.title = f"Open for current prices:" # modify the embeds title
    embed.description = f"{range1} to {range2}" # modify the embeds desc

    await message.edit(embeds=embeds) # edit the message with the new embed
```

Comment: Even when running this code, I get a traceback error when editing the message with the new embed because the object of type Embed is not JSON serializable.

Comment: hmm, thats strange as it worked fine when i tested it. Maybe you restarted the bot (which resets embed_id). Also did you update the channel in `bot.get_channel()` to the one you need? Are you able to show the full error (cause it should show what line the it originates on)

Comment: When testing, I notice embed_id updates with the correct message id. The channel is the correct channel. The error is on the last line of editEmbed,

    await message.edit(embeds=embeds) 

I get an TypeError Exception.
Object of type Embed is not JSON serializable. But the embed formats fine in my code. 

I've also tried 

    await message.edit(embeds=embed) ,


I'm still having no luck.

Comment: Maybe try: deleting lines from `embeds=...` onwards and replacing that with: `embed=discord.Embed(title="Open for current prices:", description=f"{range1} to {range2}")` and then `await message.edit(embed=embed)`.